# React-three-fiber - importing Canvas and useFrame causes webpack to fault

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-three-fiber

I am building an app from scratch with react-three-fiber. I have added three.js and react-three-fiber, but when I import the canvas or useFrame into a file, I get a webpack error.

```
import { Canvas, useFrame } from 'react-three-fiber';
```

The error

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-three-fiber/web.js
Module parse failed: /Users/joshuafoxworth/Sites/jfReactThree/jfthree/node_modules/react-three-fiber/web.js Unexpected token (144:46)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| }
| let catalogue = {};
| const extend = objects => void (catalogue = { ...catalogue,
|   ...objects
| });
 @ ./src
```

My webpack file

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/
    }, {
      test: /\.s?css$/,
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        'css-loader',
        'sass-loader'
      ]
    }]
  },
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    historyApiFallback: true
  }
}
```

Comment: is it the "..." object spread? you probably need babel-env which takes care of modern js features. btw, why not just create-react-app?